# smartcard-insert/remove not fired

Tags: javascript, mozilla

I am trying to use the Mozilla crypto object in JavaScript. 
Here is my rather simple code in JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// Handler for .ready() called
register();
});

function onSmartCardChange() {
// window.location.reload();
console.log('insert-remove');
}
function register() {   
window.crypto.enableSmartCardEvents = true; 
document.addEventListener("smartcard-insert", onSmartCardChange, false);
document.addEventListener("smartcard-remove", onSmartCardChange, false);
console.log('version='+window.crypto.version);
}
```

The version of the crypto object is written in the console window.
But an event is not fired whenever I plug/unplug my USB gadget.
In ControlPanel/Device manager the smart card seems OK. I also installed Charismatics and Cryptovision software.

Why do not I get an event when I insert/remove the USB gadget?
Is it possible that something is wrong with my setup?

Thanks,
donescamillo@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

I had some luck. I added the device in Firefox/Tools/Options/encryption/SecurityDevices. Now When I restart Firefox, plug the reader, start Firefox, unplug reader, I get an event. In any other case (plugging in reader again, starting Firefox without reader and plugging reader in) I do not get an event.
Could the problem be in the DLL specified when I added the reader to Firefox?

Thank you
donescamillo@gmail.com